# Keeping track of key presses in Canvas

Tags: javascript, keyboard, html5-canvas

I'm trying to keep track of the last 4 key presses using canvas in a game loop.

```
var lastKeys = []; // array to hold last 4 key presses
window.addEventListener("keydown", key_down, false); // key down
window.addEventListener("keyup", key_up, false); // key up

var keycode = "";
if (key.left  == true)  keycode = "left";
if (key.right == true)  keycode = "right";
if (key.up    == true)  keycode = "up";
if (key.down  == true)  keycode = "down";

And later on in the draw phase...
// add new element
lastKeys.unshift(keycode);
// remove last element
lastKeys.pop();
```

The lastKeys array should record `[up, down, left right]`, it'll just record `[right, right, right right]`, on the in example below nothing. - because every tick it'll record the last keypress and overwrite things. Only I'm a little confused as to how to fix that.

Can someone help me out, please?

Minimum code is as follows:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Minimum</title>
<link href = "stylesheet.css" rel = "stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
<!-- get keys -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/keys.js"></script>
<!-- call last -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
// declare canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),


  key =
  {
    right: false,
    left: false,
    up: false,
    down: false,
  }

  const canvasW = canvas.width;
  const canvasH = canvas.height;

// end canvas declarations


//vegetables
// -------------------------------
var lastKeys = [];
var keyCode = -1;


// initalise 
function init()
{

  // initialise keys
  window.addEventListener("keydown", key_down, false); // key down
  window.addEventListener("keyup", key_up, false); // key up

  // window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e)
  // {
  //   keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  // });

  // window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)
  // {
  //   keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  // });

}

// call initialization
init();


// Draw frames
setInterval( render, 16 );




function render()
{
   get_keys();

}

function get_keys()
{

  if (key.left     === true) keyCode = 37;
  if (key.up       === true) keyCode = 39;
  if (key.right    === true) keyCode = 38;
  if (key.down     === true) keyCode = 40;
  console.log("K: " + keyCode);

  // add new element
  lastKeys.unshift(keyCode);
  // remove last element
  lastKeys.pop();

  console.log(lastKeys);
}
```

keys.js

```
// declare canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),


  key =
  {
    right: false,
    left: false,
    up: false,
    down: false,
  }

  const canvasW = canvas.width;
  const canvasH = canvas.height;

// end canvas declarations


//vegetables
// -------------------------------
var lastKeys = [];
var keyCode = -1;


// initalise 
function init()
{

  // initialise keys
  window.addEventListener("keydown", key_down, false); // key down
  window.addEventListener("keyup", key_up, false); // key up

  // window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e)
  // {
  //   keys[e.keyCode] = true;
  // });

  // window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)
  // {
  //   keys[e.keyCode] = false;
  // });

}

// call initialization
init();


// Draw frames
setInterval( render, 16 );




function render()
{
   get_keys();

}

function get_keys()
{

  if (key.left     === true) keyCode = 37;
  if (key.up       === true) keyCode = 39;
  if (key.right    === true) keyCode = 38;
  if (key.down     === true) keyCode = 40;
  console.log("K: " + keyCode);

  // add new element
  lastKeys.push(keyCode);
  if (lastKeys.length > 4)
  {
    // remove last element
    lastKeys.pop();
  }

  console.log(lastKeys);
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813236/3877726

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the event on the whole document then focus on the canvas with [tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) or by making your own focus like the code below

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('someCanvas');
const log = document.getElementById('log');
let lastDownTarget
console.log(canvas, log);

 document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        lastDownTarget = event.target;
        alert('mousedown');
    }, false);



document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(lastDownTarget == canvas) {
      log.textContent += e.code;
    }
}, false);


document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
if(lastDownTarget == canvas) {
    log.textContent += e.code ;
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="someCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<p id="log"></p>
```